# Como posso chamar uma função jQuery de dentro do PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Criei uma pequena animação com jQuery tipo aquele `alert("mensagem")` que irá mostrar se o cadastro deu certo ou não. Como posso chamar essa função (animação) do jQuery através do PHP?

Eis um exemplo:

```
<?php
$cad = "INSERT INTO bla bla bla VALUES bla bla bla";
$sql = mysql_query($cad);
if($sql){
   chamar a função do jquery;
}else{
   chamar outra função do jquery;
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP roda no servidor, jQuery no cliente. O que você pode fazer é "fabricar" no PHP um HTML que só chame o que quiser, conforme a postagem indicada no link acima.

Comment: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/